# What does $_GET['key'] return if the key is not set?

Tags: php, arrays, get

What does $_GET return when the index is not set? (Couldn't find anything in php manual about $_GET.)

I wrote this to check, if the $_GET['id'] isset - and if it is not, set $id to false:

```
<?php $id = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? $_GET['id'] : false ?>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$_GET is just an ordinary array, so it behaves exactly the same as any other array.

This means, it will return NULL to the variable and raise the "undefined index" notice when you call a non-existing index.

The only thing you need to be aware of with $_GET is that is contains unsafe (user-modifiable) data

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that so I use prepared statements for SQL as that id from get goes to query.
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

Unset indexes have the value NULL. Accessing them will result in a notice being raised (unless your error level is set to swallow notices).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that isset() is a language construct rather than a function, and that is why entering `$_GET['nonexistent_key']` within isset() does not cause a notice to be raised.

Answer (score 2):

```
var_dump($_GET['nonexistent']); // outputs NULL
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Answer (score 1):

There's an example in the manual: [PHP: $_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

The relevant part of the example script is:

```
if(isset($_GET["a"])) echo "a is set\n";
```

That part of the script prints out "a is set" when `a` is passed as a parameter through the URL.  http://path/to/script.php?a

Answer (score 0):

If the index is not set, running `isset()` on that index within `$_GET` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

[`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) is a [superglobal](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

As such, it follows the rules for accessing array keys:

> Attempting to access an array key which
>   has not been defined is the same as
>   accessing any other undefined
>   variable: an `E_NOTICE`-level error
>   message will be issued, and the result
>   will be `NULL`.